# Unknown space to the right of the grid view

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, android-layout, space

My xml code is:

```
    <GridView android:id="@+id/gridView_calendar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" android:numColumns="5"/>
```

But there appear to the right of the gridView a blank. Its size seems for scroll bar. I don't know how it comes. Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Already solved. It's the left space for GridView.

Set screen wide is totalX. gridView node wide is deltaX, grid count is n, then the unknown space is:
totalX - deltaX*n.

But is there any api to avoid this space?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
```

or any other stretchMode, see:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:stretchMode